# SendGrid: templates and substitution tags

Tags: java, sendgrid

I've created a sendgrid template in order to be able to build my emails according to users' information. By now, it's really straightsorward:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div>&lt;%body%&gt;</div>  
  <div>Hi there&nbsp;:username!</div>  
  <div>Please, click on here to complete Accoung Activation: :activation</div>  
  <div>Please, bear with us.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As far I've been to figure out I'm able to replace tokens (`:username` and `:activation`).

Nevertheless, I don't quite understand how to build it on java. Up to now, I've been able to write this code in order to send an email with a template:

```
String activationUri = "http://activation uri.sample.com/activation";
String address = "sample@sample.com";

Email from = new Email("no-reply@facetz.zone");
String subject = "Account activation mail request";
Email to = new Email(address);
Content content = new Content("text/plain", activationUri);
Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);
mail.setTemplateId("7928c2b2-c5a9-4918-a035-db5b7aae532b");

SendGrid sg = new SendGrid("api_key");
Request request = new Request();
try {
  request.method = Method.POST;
  request.endpoint = "mail/send";
  request.body = mail.build();

  Response response = sg.api(request);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw MailGenerationException.create(address, ex);
}
```

As you can see I've set the `templateId`, nevertheless, I'm not able to get how to:

1. Set template version.
2. Add token substitutions.

By other hand:

1. Which's the difference between `section tags` and `substitution tags` and `<%subject%>` and `<%body%>` tags?

Please, I've really took a look on documentation. Up to now, I've not been able to understand everything I've posed.

Comment: Here are some examples too: [sendgrid-java](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/tree/master/examples)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do something similar, but I couln't find a way to do it with one request.

The template that will be used is always the "active" one, so, to choose a different version, you must first call the templates/versions endpoint and "activate" it.

Assuming you're using the API version 3, then you would do somethins like this (before actually sending the email):

```
Request request = new Request();
try {
  request.method = Method.PATCH;
  request.endpoint = "templates/" + templateId + "/versions/" + versionId;
  request.body = "{\"active\": \"1\"}";

  Response response = sg.api(request);
  if (response.status == 200)
    // success
  else
    // failure
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw MailGenerationException.create(address, ex);
}
```

To retrieve the list of template versions, you need to call the [templates endpoint](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Transactional_Templates/templates.html#-GET)... then the use of a version becomes a little tedious xD.

For the substitutions, you must build a Personalization object:

```
Personalization obj = new Pesrsonalization();
obj.addSubstitution("tag", "value");
// Etc.
```

The Personalization class is very useful, as it can hold the recipients (CC, BCC and TO) and other data.

The **<%body%>** tag gets replaced by whatever you send in the mail.body, and the **<%subject%>** gets replaced by the subject set in the Personalization object (or the mail.subject). The only difference with any other tag is that these don't need to be set through the Personalization object.

By the way, the subject can contain other tags tha will be replaced too.

Hope this helps you.